# What is wrong with this postgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm a PostgreSQL (v8.4) newbie, and I'm trying to get some simple functions written.  My first experiment, however, is already ending in dismal failure.  I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 7: begin;
```

... and I don't see the problem.  This looks right, according to the documentation I've been reviewing.

```
create or replace function create_user(
    user_name varchar(250),
    email_address varchar(250),
    approved boolean,
    email_is_unique boolean
    ) returns boolean as $$

begin;  

if email_is_unique
    && exists(select null from users as u where u.email = email_address) then

    raise exception 'The email address specified is already in use, and email addresses are configured to be unique.';
end if;

insert into users
    (
    user_name,
    email
    )
values
    (
    user_name,
    email_address
    );

return true;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the semicolon after `begin`