# Postgresql not creating db with “createdb” as superuser, yet not outputting errors

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am working with a fresh postgresql install, with 'postgres' super user. Logged in via:

```
sudo -u postgres psql


postgres=# createdb database
postgres-# \list
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
                                                             : postgres=CTc/postgres
```

No errors, yet table is not being created. Any ideas?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537576/what-is-wrong-with-this-postgresql-query

Answer (score 348, accepted):

`createdb` is a command line utility which you can run from **bash** and not from psql. 
To create a database from **psql**, use the `create database` statement like so:

```
create database [databasename];
```

Note: be sure to always end your SQL statements with `;`

Answer (score 122):

Late to the party, but the accepted answer doesn't explain why no error is displayed. And as this is something Postgres newcomers often stumble upon, I wanted to add that.

---

TL/TR: always end your SQL statements with `;`

---

Because the `createdb database` did not end with `;` `psql` thinks the statement isn't finished and waits for more input. This is indicated by the prompt changing from `postgres=#` to `postgres-#`. An extremely subtle change that I wish `psql` would do differently (more "prominent").

By entering the meta-command `\list` the "current" SQL statement is "aborted" without executing it.

If the `createdb` had been ended with a `;` the output would have been:

```
postgres=> createdb foobar;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createdb"
LINE 1: createdb foobar;
        ^
postgres=>
```

Clearly showing that something was wrong.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed subtle but deadly. I was having this issue for quite some time. The first time you run the command with a semicolon you'll get the error because `createdb` isn't valid. But then repeating the exact same command with `create database` instead of `createdb` along with a semicolon works perfectly.

Comment: @Helsing: that's what I wrote, I just explained why there wasn't an error message even though it is invalid

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yea, I misunderstood your purpose. Upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 9):

Using a node terminal, I had to run:

```
psql -U postgres
```

[enter your password]

then ...

```
CREATE DATABASE dbadmin;
```

---

What is confusing is that I entered these same commands before and it didn't work. Only after logging out and logging back in, was I able to use this standard command from the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-createdb.html

Comment: same for me, had to log out and log back in to make it work

Answer (score 5):

I was in this situation not long ago. In case someone else experiences this, considering that the command prompt shows `postgres-#` you can execute the pending createdb command by simply typing `;` and the return key.

Answer (score 5):

Create new data base in PostgreSQL is very simple, execute this command on Linux (CentOS 7 example):

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database MyDb;"
```