# drop db in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I try `dropdb mydbname` in shell. It do not give any error. But still when I call `\l` it is still there.

I logged into the postgres server using `sudo -u postgres psql`.

Other than my main concern I need to know how to go into the database other than just staying outside of it. (as a example if I want to list the tables)

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question. I am not able to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Could you please show your terminal output for `dropdb mydbname` and psql's `\l` meta-command?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct Postgres server?

Comment: -1 no version shown, no command-line output copied, low effort question. You've been around long enough I'd expect better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to drop database you can use SQL command (but I do not understand why dropdb didn't work) `DROP DATABASE mydbname`:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "DROP DATABASE mydbname"
```

It would be good to check if database is not used:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'mydbname';
```

The `sudo -u postgres psql` connects to postgres database. You need to specify database: `sudo -u postgres psql mydbname` and then you can use metdata commands like \d, \dt, \dv, ...

Comment: dropdb should do just the same thing

Comment: 99% of the tasks to administrate a PostgreSQL database does not require su or sudo to the 'postgres' system user.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "shell" ... do you mean the `psql` shell, not the unix command line shell?

I'd say you're running into this issue:

[Postgresql not creating db with “createdb” as superuser, yet not outputting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13321005/398670)

ie you're trying to use `dropdb` as a psql command, when it's a unix shell command. You're not getting an error because of this:

[In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect)

You didn't terminate the command with a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing the comma(;)? This command worked for me:

```
drop database <database_name>;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem. I have used postgres mainly through my code. The command line does not throw errors when you miss the semi-colon `;`

Answer (score 2):

Server should be running, then:

```
dropdb <database name>
```

If server is not running, first try:

```
pg_ctl start -D <mylocal_db_path> -l <mylogfile.log>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdb -h <ip> -p 5432 -U postgres --if-exists --echo <dbname>
```