# Correct PostgreSQL functionality

Tags: postgresql, postgresapp

I have installed Postgres.app in Mac, and I have set the PATH variable to run the psql command.

[image]

Now I would like to create a new user and new database for a project that I'm creating. Nevertheless, when I execute a new command in terminal, it doesn't prompt me anything, and I don't know if my command was executed correctly.

Even if I write dummy words, it doesn't tell me anything:

[image]

Also, if I want to enter to the postgres user, it doesn't allow me, sending me the next error:

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?.

Regards.

Comment: I believe you need to terminate a postgresql command with a semicolon. As for logging in as postgres, I'm not sure.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13321005/330315

Comment: First things first - every SQL command needs to end with a delimiter which happens to be `;`.

Also, commands like `createdb` and `createuser` are not to be invoked from within `psql`, but from the console itself.

Of course, there are equivalents like `CREATE DATABASE <name>` or `CREATE USER <name> [WITH] <options>`.

Comment: And for example, if I want to run it from bash, why does it tell me that the user postgres doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `;` to each of your PostgreSQL - commands.