# PostgreSQL: pg_dump does nothing in command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I opened an SQL Shell (psql) and entered my information: username, port, host, database and password.

Then the name of the database popped up like so

```
Testing_Database-#
```

Then I attempted to dump a table into a file like so

```
pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > plzwork.sql
```

Nothing showed up on my machine.  I quickly got back

```
Testing_Database-#
```

I searched my entire computer for it then I read online to try

```
pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > C:\plzwork.sql
```

It didn't work either. It threw an error, so I tried another example

```
pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > "C:\\plzwork.sql"
```

and got

```
Testing_Database-#
```

But still, it wasn't in the C drive as expected. So, I am now wondering am I supposed to get a notification of completion? If it is working, why isn't it sending it where I can find it.

Also, I tried my own personal localhost to do a dump and got the same results.

Comment: `pg_dump` is **not** a SQL or `psql` command. You run that on the command line of your _operating system_ e.g. `cmd.exe`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13321005/330315

Comment: ok im sorry first i was told it wasnt an sql command so i did it with psql. now i shouldnt use cmd.exe cause i loggin cia command prompt.

pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > plzwork.sql 
in command. and i get access denied

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking to use pg_dump, the command is meant for normal command prompt not for psql command prompt.

Go to your command line and run the pg_dump tablename dbname > filename.sql
You can pwd just to make sure where you are.

Winscp the file to destination server. In the destination server,log into the psql command.

Run psql dbname < filename.sql

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how I missed this detail even though I had done backups several times in the past, and I kept wondering why it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Mac user:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > plzwork.sql`

As @MrKarma4u mentioned, this has to be run from the regular command prompt (not from psql)

Answer (score 0):

when running that terminal command you should identify a output file with ">" plus the file name "result.txt" and ensure your pathing is correct

it should look like this

> pg_dump -h BigSever -p 5432 -t customer_order > "/path/to/file/plzwork.sql"